# About Resizing Buttons on PictureBox

Tags: c#, forms, panel, picturebox, tablelayoutpanel

I have a project using **a map animation(gif file) on PictureBox**. Also on my map, I have 4 buttons that should be on my main streets.

I have a problem about resizing my form. In example,

[image: True]

When resize:

[image: False]

As you can see, button locations are incorrect.

**Form layout order : MainForm > TableLayoutPanel > Panel > PictureBox > Buttons**

Is there any suggestion about that ? 
Thanks in advance

***Note : When I use a static image for my Panel instead of PictureBox, it works. However I must use a gif image. That would be ok if anyone suggest about that also.***

Comment: what do that 4 buttons do ?

Comment: They will show information like a popup when mousehover event triggered